# std::filesystem::copy копирует файлы, а не папку

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Суть проблемы - команда копирует только файлы, но не вложенные в директорию папки. Если указать директорию выше, т.е. скопировать полностью папку - вообще ничего не копируется. Как решить? Могу приложить код, но он супер-примитивный, поэтому и спрашиваю в чем пролема и как исправить.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    filesystem::copy("G:\\test\\test_copy", "C:\\copy");
}
```

Comment: Гляньте на https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_options, и конкретно на recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь в решении Harry и Alex F:
Если хотите, чтобы команда copy работала как надо, т.е. копировала директорию со вложенными папками и файлами, то надо в параметрах добавить рекурсию:

```
std::filesystem::copy_options::recursive
```

Всем спасибо огромное за помощь!